# Neo4j HA cluster in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, neo4j, high-availability

I have a Neo4j HA cluster setup in AWS with three EC2 instances ( One master and two slaves). My application is configured in such a way that it communicates with the master node only. Now, my question is, if master node fails, how my application will get connected to the new master node (any one from the two slaves)?

Thanks,
Debojit

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a load balancer between your application and the Neo4j cluster. See the [reference manual for a haproxy setup](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/ha-haproxy.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response. What if the EC2 instance where haproxy is installed and configured fails or become unavailable?

Comment: You can run multiple instances of haproxy.

Comment: how can we assign a single IP to multuple instance of haproxy using keepalived in aws? I dont find a way to reserve private IP for multuple instance in aws.